# How do I launch WinMerge from Vim?

Tags: vim, windows-7, winmerge

On my Mac, I use this to diff my current buffer:

```
nnoremap <Space>d
\   :silent w! /tmp/vim_current_buffer<cr>
\   :silent !gdiff "%" /tmp/vim_current_buffer<cr>
```

(gdiff is my graphical differ)

Now I'm using Windows 7, and I'm trying to get this code to work with [WinMerge](http://winmerge.org/). But, I can't figure-out how to launch [WinMerge](http://winmerge.org/) from the command line.

---

**Update**

I can run WinMerge with:

```
nnoremap <Space>m :!"C:\Program Files (x86)\WinMerge\WinMergeU.exe"<cr>
```

But I can't get it to open two files. Adding the extra slashes doesn't work. I get this when I try it:

```
C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /c C:\\Program\ Files\ (x86)\\WinMerge\\WinMergeU.ex
e
'C:\\Program\' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
shell returned 1
Hit any key to close this window...
```

This is what I have so far:

```
nnoremap <Space>d
\   :silent w! "C:\tmp\vim_current_buffer"<cr>
\   :silent !"C:\Program Files (x86)\WinMerge\WinMergeU.exe" "C:\tmp\vim_current_buffer" "%" <cr>
```

Is there anyone to see the error?

Comment: is `vimdiff` not good enough?

Answer (score 1):

Do you know the path to WinMerge's executable?  It would be something like `C:\Program Files\WinMerge\WinMergeU.exe`. You should be able to put that in instead of `gdiff`, but put a backslash before each original backslash and space in the name (e.g. `C:\\Program\ Files\\WinMerge\\WinMergeU.exe`).